# SQL query. Very restricted due to environment. Is it even possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, subquery

I'have a specific problem. I need get some some data from database. I have a mechanism to retrieve data from a program. I need to use it, no modifications possible. The original query is:

```
SELECT it_Symbol AS Symbol, tt_Name AS Nazwa, tt_Price AS Cena, 
       tt_Quantity AS Ilosc, tt_Id
FROM  tr__Transaction INNER JOIN  tr_Item 
                      ON tt_TransId=tr_Id LEFT OUTER JOIN  it__Item 
                      ON tt_ItemId = it_Id RIGHT JOIN  reg_Site 
                      ON tr_SiteId = rs_Id LEFT OUTER JOIN  it_ItemSite 
                      ON it_Id = is_ItemId
WHERE tt_TransId=@transId 
GROUP BY tt_Id, tt_Quantity, tr_Id, it_Name, tt_Price,it_Symbol, 
         is_Name, tt_Name, tt_ItemId, tt_Id
```

The problem is that `I need to get some additional data from tr__Transaction table.`
It has a field `tr_Source`. I need this fields value, but for `tr__transaction` records which have `tr_Id` listed in returned `tt_Id` field.

Any way to do a subquery returning values dependant on tt_Id column values?
Or maybe any other joins combination? I've spend whole week with this, and have no more ideas or skills to do this:/
Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean no modifications possible?  do you want a new query even though you can not modify it?

Comment: If `tr_Id -> tt_Id`, why don't you just add `,tr_Source` to the end of the SELECT column list? Adding and extra column to the end unlikely to break your existing code (unless you do column.Count calculations).

Comment: tt_Id is in tr__Transaction and tr_Id is in it__Item ?

Comment: @Jester: It's the other way around (my guess :)

Comment: one sugestion always when you write a select statment write table reference I know it is more writing but when you get used to it you will see the benefit of that even if the name is unique. you can also use aliases to reduce the writing of long table names

Comment: I can modify the query but cannot have more parameters. Software executes the query giving it tr__Transaction.tr_Id.

Comment: As @Kaf said - why cannot you just add tr_Source to the select statement?

Comment: Table tr_Item have columns like tt_Id and tt_transId.
I get the results based on tr_Id. And I have lets say 10 tr_item records.
Every tr_Item record have tt_transId lets say value '1' and tt_Id value lets say 10,11,12,... and so. 10 records.
There are tr__transaction records with tr_id 10,11,12,... which have my desired tr_Source value.
Kinda complicated to explain:/

Comment: I cannot add just tr_source becouse it gives me tr_source value of tr__transaction record with (looking at my previous comment) tr_Id 1. All the same. But should be diffirent, for every tr__transaction.tr_Id = tt_id for every returned result.

Answer (score 0):

Ok still don't know exactly what you need but it is an atempt to clean up the question. So this is a working version of the answer since you can't format code in comments.

Please explain if some relations are wrong.

you can always join tables multiple times under different conditions as long as they have different aliases.

For instance:

```
SELECT c.it_Symbol AS Symbol, a.tt_Name AS Nazwa, a.tt_Price AS Cena, 
       a.tt_Quantity AS Ilosc, a.tt_Id, f.tr_Source 
FROM  tr__Transaction a 
    INNER JOIN  tr_Item b
                      ON a.tt_TransId=b.tr_Id 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  it__Item c
                      ON a.tt_ItemId = c.it_Id 
    RIGHT JOIN  reg_Site d
                      ON a.tr_SiteId = d.rs_Id 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN  it_ItemSite e
                      ON c.it_Id = e.is_ItemId
   LEFT OUTER JOIN tr__Transaction f
                      ON c.tt_id = f.tr_id
WHERE a.tt_TransId=@transId 
GROUP BY a.tt_Id, a.tt_Quantity, a.tr_Id, c.it_Name, a.tt_Price,c.it_Symbol, 
         e.is_Name, a.tt_Name, a.tt_ItemId, a.tt_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you question correctly, but assuming you are saying that the Original SQL statement cannot be changed (ie, it's in a read-only View). Then you can wrap it around another SELECT statement.

```
SELECT  tblOriginal.*, tblExtend.tt_Source
FROM    (
        SELECT it_Symbol AS Symbol, tt_Name AS Nazwa, tt_Price AS Cena, 
               tt_Quantity AS Ilosc, tt_Id
        FROM  tr__Transaction INNER JOIN  tr_Item 
                              ON tt_TransId=tr_Id LEFT OUTER JOIN  it__Item 
                              ON tt_ItemId = it_Id RIGHT JOIN  reg_Site 
                              ON tr_SiteId = rs_Id LEFT OUTER JOIN  it_ItemSite 
                              ON it_Id = is_ItemId
        WHERE tt_TransId=@transId 
        GROUP BY tt_Id, tt_Quantity, tr_Id, it_Name, tt_Price,it_Symbol, 
                 is_Name, tt_Name, tt_ItemId, tt_Id
        ) AS tblOriginal
        INNER JOIN tr__Transaction AS tblExtend
        ON tblOriginal.tt_Id = tblExtend.tt_Id
```

But I suspect your problem is more complicated that that as you've spent over a week on it. In that case, can you elaborate?

Comment: As I tried to explain and write more specifation with the query problem. I've simplified it by removing most of fields, and achieved half-solution and new facts.
For the moment I'm really shamed that i didn't saw some of it:/ Realy hard week.
I think that can solve the problem through the weekend, even if not it will have a new form.
Thanks for all of You that tried to help in my desperate call:)
Problem not actual, can be removed becouse it don't bring anything, just needless garbage on stackoverflow.
Sorry for problem.